# How to provide Docker Credentials for AWS CodeBuild automatic image pull

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-cdk, aws-codebuild

I have a CodeBuild project that pulls an image from a public Docker repository. I'm running into the known issue of too many pulls, so I want to login to Docker and pull the image because I have a valid Docker license.

However, I can't seem to find any documentation on how to set my credentials in CodeBuild. The only examples I see, are logging in via the `buildspec.yml` and then pulling the docker image. This does not work for me because I'm setting the docker image in the CodeBuild configuration.

I'm using CDK and this is my current CodeBuild configuration:

```
const myCodeBuild = new codeBuild.Project(this, 'myCodeBuild', {
  source: githubsrc,
  secondarySources: [ githubsrc2 ],
  role: new BuildRole(this, 'myCodeBuildRole').role,
  buildSpec: codeBuild.BuildSpec.fromObject(buildSpec),
  environment: {
    buildImage: codeBuild.LinuxBuildImage.fromDockerRegistry('salesforce/salesforcedx:latest-rc-full'
  },
});
```

This creates a CodeBuild project that will automatically use the provided Docker Image. There is never a chance to login before it is pulled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`fromDockerRegistry`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_codebuild.LinuxBuildImage.html#static-fromwbrdockerwbrregistryname-options) supports authentication. To use it, create a Secrets Manager secret that contains the `username` and `password` fields with your Docker Hub credentials and pass it to the function. ([Documentation reference for the secret format](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/how-to-use-docker-images-from-a-private-registry-in-aws-codebuild-for-your-build-environment/))

Using the example from the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_codebuild-readme.html#images):

```js
environment: {
  buildImage: codebuild.LinuxBuildImage.fromDockerRegistry('my-registry/my-repo', {
    secretsManagerCredentials: secrets,
  }),
},
```

`secrets` is your Secrets Manager secret here.

Comment: Can you give me an example of the key pair for the secret? Its not described anywhere. I see you have `username` and `password` as the key, but is there documentation for that?

Comment: Sure, added a link to the answer.